# Is it possible to install Roundcube on shared server ?

Tags: email, cpanel, webmail, roundcube

Is it possible to install [roundcube](http://roundcube.net) on Shared linux 
server running Cpanel. I heard from my service provider that it isn't. Well is it possible atleast on  Dedicated IP... Please advice. Thanking in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Ahoy,

cPanel ships with Roundcube already installed on the server by default with cPanel.  You can access roundcube though the webmail interface using any of the email accounts hosted on that server.  The webmail login that you can access roundcube through is at http://example.com/webmail -or- https://example.com:2096

cPanel uses a specially modified version of roundcube to help address issues like passing cPanel authentication data to roundcube to make logins easier.  cPanel's roundcube files are stored at:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/roundcube
```

To update roundcube on a cPanel server you can use the following command.  Additionally if you use the --force flag, roundcube will be reinstalled.

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/update-roundcube
```

cPanel Roundcube also has a special logging location at:

```
/var/cpanel/roundcube/log
```

cPanel Roundcube's Primary Configuration file

```
/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/roundcube/config/main.inc.php
```

By default roundcube will use MySQL, however it is possible to update roundcube to use sqlite, an quicker and more efficient database driver for roundcube.  There are dangers in this conversion (ie. address book loss, roundcube user preferences loss).  The command to convert roundcube to sqlite is:

```
/scripts/convert_roundcube_mysql2sqlite
/scripts/convert_roundcube_mysql2sqlite $username
```

To update an sqlite roundcube (--force to reinstall)

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/update-roundcube-sqlite
```

Additionally since roundcube is a php script, you can download roundcube from http://roundcube.net/download/ and install it into any cPanel account if your usage requires customizations that cPanel will not support.

Chears!

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is 100 % possible for sure( I have an example in production)
The only thing to consider is, there may be some missing components that Roundcube requires. If this is is the case, just submit a ticket for your hosting provider, they will certainly install the missing components.

If you want to install SSL for your Roundcube, for sure you also need a dedicated IP.